# Redirect including path to new domain?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Hey guys I need the htaccess code to do the following after moving domains.

From:

```
http://www.techau.tv/blog/review-d-link-2890al-wireless-modem-router/
```

To:

```
http://techau.com.au/review-d-link-2890al-wireless-modem-router/
```

So in the change of domain, I dropped the `www` and the `/blog`.

Comment: do you still own techau.tv?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your .htaccess file on http://www.techau.tv :

```
## 301 Redirect Entire Directory
RedirectMatch 301 http://www.techau.tv/blog/(.*) http://techau.com.au/$1
RedirectMatch 301 http://techau.tv/blog/(.*) http://techau.com.au/$1
```

Seems to use a regex to do it.

I generated it with this tool by the way: http://www.htaccessredirect.com/

Comment: Have tried this and it's not working. A visit to http://techAU.tv does redirect, but any deep links just result in a 404.

Comment: damn, sounds like @Prix answer is probably the way to go?

Comment: @Snipergirl both answers are right, he is probably having issues with file location or conflict with another `.htaccess`.

Comment: should the .htaccess file be in the public_html or www folders or both ?

Comment: public_html/ is usually the same as www/ - the latter tends to be a shortcut to the former, but you can check whether that's the case on your server.